# Unit Testing a Method that Interacts with the Excel Interop Library

Tags: c#, unit-testing, object-oriented-analysis

I'm trying to become better at writing cleaner code and developing automated tests for methods in applications so as to test the application quicker and write more flexible and extensible code. While I think I understand the basics of Unit Testing, I'm having trouble developing a test for a specific method. I've recently taken an online course on Unit Testing and I learned that in order to write Unit Tests for methods that touch external resources, you should create a class that implements the code that interacts with that external resource and extract an interface for that class so the a Mock instance can be created from the extracted interface. I think using the Excel Interop library qualifies as touching an external resource and the method I'm working on right now is meant to save an Excel file to the user's computer. The code for this method can be seen below.

```
    public void Save()
    {
        if (DoesFileExistInDirectory())
        {
            semesterGradeInformationWorkbook.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            semesterGradeInformationWorkbook.SaveAs(LocationAsURL);
        }
    }

    private bool DoesFileExistInDirectory()
    {
        return File.Exists(LocationAsURL);
    }
```

in this case, if the file exists already the save function can just be called on the workbook. However, if the file doesn't exist the SaveAs operation is called on the workbook to save the file to that location. The code for the whole class can be seen here.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace GradeCalculator
{
    public class ExcelWorksheet
    {
        private Excel.Application excelApplication;
        private Excel.Workbook semesterGradeInformationWorkbook;
        private Excel.Worksheet classInformationWorksheet;

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string LocationAsURL { get; private set; }
        public int UsedRows
        {
            get { return this.classInformationWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count; }
        }

        public int UsedColumns
        {
            get { return this.classInformationWorksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count; }
        }

        public ExcelWorksheet(string name)
        {
            InitializeExcel();

            Name = name;

            LocationAsURL = Path.Combine(Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultDirectory, Name + ".xlsx");

        }

        private void InitializeExcel()
        {
            excelApplication = new Excel.Application();

            semesterGradeInformationWorkbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Add();

            classInformationWorksheet = semesterGradeInformationWorkbook.ActiveSheet;

            excelApplication.Visible = true;
        }

        public void Save()
        {
            if (DoesFileExistInDirectory())
            {
                semesterGradeInformationWorkbook.Save();
            }
            else
            {
                semesterGradeInformationWorkbook.SaveAs(LocationAsURL);
            }
        }

        private bool DoesFileExistInDirectory()
        {
            return File.Exists(LocationAsURL);
        }
    }
}
```

Any tips on how to refactor the code so that it is more extensible and I can write a unit test for it? Any other tips on how to improve the class and methods to better implement a better object oriented design would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: This looks more like integration test not unit test ... also is there any reasons to use Excel interop instead using OpenXml instead?

Comment: Abstractions, abstractions, abstractions. Decouple from 3rd party implementation details.

Comment: @Selvin Perhaps it is, how would I tell the difference? Also there's no particular reason to use Excel interop, it's just what I've used in the past.

Comment: @Nkosi If it is possible and advisable to unit test this method, can you give me any practical help or suggestions on the best way to use abstractions and decouple from the 3rd party implementation? I understand the idea, but this seems like a complicated process in this case but I might be overlooking something or I'm failing to fully understand.

Comment: Your implementation is tightly coupled to the Excel Interop library - this makes it difficult to _unit_ test without touching the file system and opening Excel in your tests. Consider adding a Facade that wraps your particular usage of the Excel API. Also, look into the Dependency Inversion Principle on how to turn that Facade into a substitutable abstraction.